# SQL Huge Read Only Table Performance Filter and Ordering

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, t-sql, indexing

I have a table with 1 billion rows that holds possible solutions to a goal setting program.
The combination of each column's value creates a successful goal path. I want to filter records to show the top 10 rows that are ordered by the choice of the user. Someone may want the lowest possible retirement age, then lowest deposit amount. Someone else may want the highest possible survival chance, then highest ending balance, ...
Here are my columns:

```
age                 tinyint
retirement_age      tinyint
retirement_length   tinyint
survival            smallint  
deposit             int   
balance_start       int
balance_end         int


SLOW 10 MIN QUERY:

select top(10) age,retirement_age,retirement_length,survival,deposit,balance_start,balance_end
from TABLE
where  
age                     >= 30 
and survival            >= 8000 --OUT OF 10000
and balance_start       <= 20000
and retirement_age      >= 60
and retirement_age      <= 75
and retirement_length   >= 10 
and retirement_length   <= 25 
and deposit             >= 1000 
and deposit             <= 20000

ORDER BY  --  (COLUMN ORDER PREFERENCES UNKNOWN)
retirement_age,   
deposit, 
retirement_length desc,
balance_end desc,
age desc, 
survival desc
```

That query takes 10 min.
All of the records are generated once, so there is no more writing/updating to the database. I was thinking I should index each column, but have not done so. The database is 30GB right now, but space is not an issue.

I have run the Estimated Execution plan:

select: 0%
parallelism: 0%
sort: 23%
table scan: 77%

Comment: I think you mean the Estimated Execution plan? ;)

Comment: Yes, thanks. The Estimated Exception Plan... :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating an index like

```
CREATE INDEX IX_TABLE ON [TABLE] 
(age,survival,balance_start,retirement_age,retirement_length,deposit) 
INCLUDE (balance_end)
```

The order of the index fields `(age,survival,balance_start,retirement_age,retirement_length,deposit)` will make a difference if not all the fields are used in the `WHERE clause`, so make sure to put them in order of most used.

Also, the order of the included columns does not make any difference.

Seeing as the table values will not change, you can create more than one such index to improve the performance of other queries where it does not use all the fields in the `WHERE clause`

Comment: Why did you use INCLUDE(balance_start, balance_end) instead of INCLUDE(balance_end)? balance start is used in the WHERE clause. I thought INCLUDE is for non indexed columns. Are you saying that no matter what column my query gives preference to order first, this one index will work for any column preference order?

Comment: That is correct, soory, I missed, that. Will correct now.

Comment: I plan on always using as many WHERE clauses as I can to filter the data down to a reasonable size before sorting

Comment: Putting all columns into only one index reduced the time by half. Instead I put each column into it's own index: CREATE INDEX IX_survival ON TABLE (survival desc) CREATE INDEX IX_age ON TABLE (age asc) etc. and it performs much better.

Comment: When you look at the execution plan, does it tell you which index it is using?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating separate indexes on each of the columns in my where and order clauses with the default order:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_age ON TABLE (age desc)  
CREATE INDEX IX_retirement_age ON TABLE (retirement_age)  
CREATE INDEX IX_retirement_length ON TABLE (retirement_length desc)  
CREATE INDEX IX_survival ON TABLE (survival desc)   
CREATE INDEX IX_deposit ON TABLE (deposit) 
CREATE INDEX IX_balance_start ON TABLE (balance_start)     
CREATE INDEX IX_balance_end ON TABLE (balance_end desc)
```